# Why isnt my picture in footer showing?

Tags: css

My footer background image is not showing. I cant figure out why.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

```
/* Footer */
}
.footer {
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
    background: url(/images/space.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
}
.footer .container {
    position: relative;
    top: 200px;
}

.footer p {
    color: #fff;
    font-size: 15px;
    margin: 0px 0 20px 0px;
    padding: 50px 0 0;
}
```

Comment: remove the `}` before `.footer`

Comment: Thank you... I overlooked it.